# ¿Cómo organizar un proyecto en Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Buenos días, estoy trabajando con un proyecto en Angularjs y después de hacer unas cuantas cosas me mandan organizar el proyecto, osea, estructurarlo. No tengo ni idea sinceramente de como puedo hacerlo. Me dieron dos componentes llamados 'información' y 'respuesta' y en cada una de ellas tenga que meter lo que corresponde de todo lo que hice en el proyecto.

No se realmente que partes del código necesitais para poder ayudarme. Si me decís edito la pregunta y añado lo que necesiteis.

Hice una parte de lo que me mandaron. Dentro de la carpeta Scripts tengo otra llamada app y dentro de esta creo la carpeta 'componentes' donde meteré 'respuesta'.

en la carpeta 'respuesta' tengo 'respuesta.js' que viene siendo esto:

```
    angular.module('formApp')
    .component('respuesta', {
        templateUrl: '/scripts/templates/respuesta.html',        
        bindings: {
            datos: '='
        },
        controller: "HacerAlgoCtrl as respuesta"
    })


angular.module('formApp').controller('HacerAlgoCtrl', hacerAlgoCtrl);

function hacerAlgoCtrl() {
    this.algo = function () {
        alert('functiona');

    }
}
```

y en la carpeta 'respuesta.html' esto:

```
<h1>Template info {{form.name}}</h1>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hay tanto para comentar sobre este tema, que por razones de tiempo te dejo dos links a guías de dos grandes! https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide/blob/master/i18n/es.md y https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Comment: Vale, muchisimas gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay un montón de información al respecto de como organizar un proyecto desde 0 "a mano" o con herramientas tipo Yeoman con generadores de scaffolding.

Dependiendo de la versión de angular que estés usando, puedes hacer más o menos cosas aunque me imagino que estás usando la 1.5.X.

Te recomiendo una lectura de estos artículos

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure

https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide/blob/master/README-es-es.md

Y a personalmente te recomendaría:

- No usar sintaxis "controller as" si estas usando angular 1.5.
- Tener un componente padre donde insertes todos los demás componentes.

Comment: vale, muchas gracias! :)